# Using dependency Walker to find missing file

Tags: dll, dependencies, dependency-walker

I have a dll that is working well on my computer but doesn't work on another computer. Apperently there is a missing dependency. I tried to use the dependency walker to find the missing file. It says:

Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "MyDllFile.DLL" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

But it doesn’t say which file is missing. Where can I find which file is missing? 
 (The dll is a native code dll and built with Visual Studio 2005 express. I already installed VS2005 Redistribution on target computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "VS2005 redistributables" and there are "VS2005 *SP1* redistributables". Maybe you need the SP1 redistributables?

You could search for "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)" to find the SP1 flavor.

Comment: Thanks. I installed it but without any success. How can I use Dependency Walker to find the dependent file that has problem?

Comment: Compiled it with VS2005 (without SP1 installed) and t worked on other computer.

Comment: I've seen depends.exe highlight the runtime (msvc*.dll) libraries when there's a problem, but I think I had to scroll down the list of modules rather than look at the dependency tree.